# What is the difference between a local storage located on the http site and another located in the https site?

Tags: javascript

I heard that there is a difference between a local storage located in the http site and another located in the https site, so what is the difference?

Comment: The difference is like if you have two files, one called "a.txt" and another called "b.txt". Both are text files. You can write the same things in both files or you can write different things in each file. Both can store text etc. The main point is that they are different files. Similarly both local storage are different "files".

Answer (score 0):

> so what is the difference?

The scheme (sometimes called "protocol") is part of the *origin* of the page. Every distinct *origin* gets its own store, isolated from the stores for other origins. Since `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` are different origins, their stores are isolated from each other just as much as the ones for `https://a.com` and `https://b.com`.

The *functionality* of the stores is the same, it's just they have different contents, because they're for different origins.